# TypeError: resolver is not a function

Tags: javascript, mongoose, axios, next.js

I am attempting to create a basic post on click in my NextJS app to a MongoDB database. The issue i am getting is `TypeError: resolver is not a function`. I understand it might be a syncronicity issue but for the life of me I cannot figure out where.

Stack used: NextJS, Axios, Mongoose.

Component code snippet calling axios:

*i know the states are updating so i am putting only the snippet that handles the request*

```
  handleSubmit = async (e: any) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    await axios
      .post('/api/roomSession', {
        roomName: this.state.roomName,
        teamName: this.state.teamName
      })
      .then((response: any) => console.log('axios call reached', response))
      .catch((error: any) => console.log('---- error! ----', error));
  };

[...]
<button onClick={this.handleSubmit}>Create</button>
[...]
```

NextJS API file:

```
import { newSession } from '../../packages/backend/mongo/connection';

const apiNewSession = async (roomName, teamName) => {
  await newSession(teamName, roomName);
};

export default apiNewSession();
```

Mongoose file:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

mongoose
  .connect(
    'mongodbconnection',
    { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true }
  )
  .then(() => {
    console.log('connected to mongoDB');
  })
  .catch(err => console.error('Connection failed: ', err));

  const sessionSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    teamName: String,
    roomName: String
  });

const Session = mongoose.model.tests || mongoose.model('tests', sessionSchema);

export const newSession = async (teamName, roomName) => {
  const session = new Session({
    teamName,
    roomName
  });
  const result = await session.save();
  mongoose.connection.close();
};
```

*Some extra info on the strange behaviour: When first time called, the code throws the aformentioned error but manages to reach the mongoDB connection and creates an EMPTY entry inside the collection (only _id, and _v).
Upon second attempt, only the error is thrown.*

Answer (score 91, accepted):

I was exporting the function incorrectly from the NextJS API file.

Correct method:
`export default apiNewSession;`

Not sure why it still happened when when i was exporting the function by default.

Comment: You can also try - export default async function apiNewSession; It works in case you wanted to export async function.

Comment: +2 so far... ;)

Comment: Man, they really could have written a better error message for that.

Answer (score 5):

My problem was that I was defining a middleware function incorrectly...

This is okay

```
/* pages/api/endpoint.js */
export default MiddleWare(handler)
```

But middleware functions shouldn't be `async`...

```
async function MiddleWare(handler) {
// ^ remove this!
  return async function (req, res) {
    // some async stuff
    next(req, res);
  }
}
```